# what is best method for core data or sqlite for iphone app with using story board?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, ios6

I want to make a small application that is based on database in back end as storage.

I want to do my first CRUD operation as-well.

kindly suggest your Best for small,intermediate or large application.

Comment: Kindly suggest me some reading material.thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html Standards by apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should start with CORE DATA.

Here is a link for one video tutorial, you can find them on your as-well.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StMBHzA7h18