# Crash on retrieving managedObjectContext from app delegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios7, delegates

So I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACESS(code=2...) error when I try to retrieve my managedObjectContext in one of my view controllers.

This is my code for the getter method:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return self.managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

This is how I try to retrieve the managedObjectContext

```
QVAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QVAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Here are the definitions in the appDelegate

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

I am using ARC and converted this [tutorial's](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/) code to ARC.

I really can't seem to be able to solve this.

Edit: Here is where it crashes https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Det.png

Comment: Please provide more context. As it stands now, the code by itself should not cause an exception, even though it is somewhat "undefined" since property `managedObjectContext` may also return `nil` (if your persistentStoreCoordinator is `nil`. However, you might very well get an exception elsewhere when using this context: you should be aware of the consequences when returning a `NSManagedObjectContext` employing the _thread confinement_ concurrency mode.

Comment: The thing is that even if I delete the code inside the method and call it, it still crashes, so it doesn't matter what is inside that. Calling that method just crashes the app.

Comment: The debugger is your friend ;)

Comment: debug that code, check where it is being crashed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963937/what-is-best-method-for-core-data-or-sqlite-for-iphone-app-with-using-story-boar/18964145#18964145 may be you will find something better over here, your code seems fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to have an infinite loop in here:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return self.managedObjectContext;
    }
```

`self.managedObjectContext` translates to `[self managedObjectContext]` which is the method you just entered.  So you are calling the accessor over and over again.

You did not copy that example correctly.

Second, you **really** should be using dependency injection instead of treating your App Delegate like a singleton.  I would strongly suggest researching DI and employing that design pattern.  It will save you a lot of pain later.

### Update 1

Where does it crash?  What line of code?  Is it `self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;` or somewhere else?  Where is your breakpoint firing in Xcode?  If it is firing at that line of code and not *inside* of the `-managedObjectContext` method then you have a problem with your App Delegate (which should not be possible).

Comment: Good point but it seems that it's not the core problem here. I can remove all the code from the method except the return and it still crashed, so it's the calling itself that crashes the app, not the content in the method I believe.

Comment: remove the `self.` from inside of that method, run again and link the screenshot.  I am still not convinced that your code is not the core issue here.  Showing the stack trace would help as well.

Comment: __"I can remove all the code from the method except the return and it still crashed"__ - If the return is still `return self.managedObjectContext` you have the same problem of calling the method from within itself as Marcus described.

Comment: @Abizern Ok, that fixed it, now I just do: return managedObjectContext; and it works.

Comment: Patience, I was about to.

Answer (score 3):

**To find the crash type simply add this code in AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            print("This is exception here ",exception)
            print(exception.callStackSymbols)
        }
return true

}
```